# What benefits could a creature gain by developing claws on its digits?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, bio-mechanics

I have an alien creature which I am currently designing, but I am hesitant in deciding whether or not it should have claws on its digits.

The creature in question is a bipedal cursorial hunter with digitigrade posture (which is also a blind, primarily hearing-based pack hunter, although I do not believe that information is as relevant to the question), but its main weapon is its mouth and the teeth within.

What are the biggest benefits of having claws on the end of a creature's digits, primarily the digits used in locomotion?

Additionally, could these potential benefits be accomplished through some other structure?

(Edit: their forelimbs are already too specialized to be used in hunting, and it is their hind limbs that would house the claws.)

Comment: Primary function of claws is grip - either in terrain or prey. Classically, claws were more often used to control and manipulate prey to keep them in place as you killed them (exceptions, obviously, but...) Lock claws into prey and now you and the prey move as one, making the kill-bite easier. Are these intelligent/tool users? We need to understand their life style to understand the usefulness of claws.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. The creatures in question are about as intelligent as something like a parrot. Something I should edit into the question is that their forelimbs are already too specialized to be used in hunting, and it is their hind limbs that would house the claws.

Answer (score 2):

> whether or not it should have claws on its digits

> cursorial hunter

It will be able to use the claws to slash prey.

> Edit: their forelimbs are already too specialized to be used in hunting, and it is their hind limbs that would house the claws.

[image: OP editing the question to say that the hind limbs would be the ones with claws]

<sup>Template: https://xkcd.com/292/</sup>

It will be able to use the claws to slash prey just like a velociraptor.

They may also use those claws for extra traction. They could maybe use those claws for digging, or kicking dirt over their nests to cover eggs.

> its main weapon is its mouth and the teeth within.

Dogs have their mouth and teeth as main weapons too. Yet they have claws for traction and digging.